# Count subject to three conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, countif

I am trying to do a COUNTIF with department and salary range as conditions.  i.e.: Department column holds `Administration` and Salary Range is between `50,000` and `60,000`.

What am I missing in my COUNTIF statement?

```
=COUNTIF(D3:D40,(AND(AND(D3:D40>=50000,D3:D40<=60000),F3:F40="Administration")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those without COUNTIFS:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((F:F="Administration")*(D:D>=50000)*(D:D<=60000))
```

For as much of ColumnsD:F as is relevant this multiplies the count of the values within the specified limits by `1` where the corresponding ColumnF value is `Administration` and by `0` otherwise, then sums the results of the products.

Answer (score 2):

Use [COUNTIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842):

```
=COUNTIFS(D3:D40,">=50000",D3:D40,"<=60000",F3:F40,"Administration")
```

This allows multiple criteria.